# Can you say: acquire or obtain business?

Tags: word-choice

When customers buy things from a store, you say:

(1) Customers give ABC Store business.

If I "turn this around", can I say:

(2) ABC Store **obtains or acquires** business from its customers.

Do these verbs work in (2)?

Comment: I would just use *gets*. If you need something more detailed, some additional context should be added.

Comment: A business "acquiring" business usually refers to one business buying out another business.  "Obtains" isn't commonly used as in #2.  If I had to pick a word, maybe "gets" or "receives".

Answer (score 1):

You can say "acquire" or "obtain" **a** business, but this refers to the acquisition of the *entire* business (by another individual or corporation). If you want to talk about an increase in the volume of commercial *transactions*, you would perhaps say an "*increase* in business", simply an "increase in sales" or an "increase in the number of customers".

If you simply want to describe the relationship between a business and its customers, you could say that the store "*gets* business from its customers", or possibly that there is a "business relationship" between the store and the customer.

However in business transactions like this the more generic term is "vendor", who *supplies* a good or service which the customer (or client) *purchases*.  It would be more common to say a vendor *delivers* or *offers* something to its customers, or that the two entities *do business* with each other.